# Push data from googlesheets to to BigQuery with Appscript- how do I set up service account to load data. I don't want to add each user to BigQuery?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-bigquery

I have build a google sheet that will be replicated 80 times for stores to enter operational data into.
This user generated data is then pushed to BigQuery with an Appscript via a button in the relevant sheet.

The script works fine, but I don't want to give each of the 80 users access to BigQuery, I would like to use a service account. As a bit of a newbie, I am not sure how to do this. I have some questions

- Do I set this service account up in GCP IAM?
- Do I assign permissions in IAM?
  If I add service account to the GoogleSheet with editor permission- I assume that I would need to modify my appscript to use the service account. Otherwise I will get the error as per screenshot [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HIr2S.png)

```
/**
 * Loads the content of a Google Drive Spreadsheet into BigQuery
 
 */
 
function loadCogsPlayupHistory() {
  // Enter BigQuery Details as variable.
  var projectId = 'myproject';
  // Dataset
  var datasetId = 'my_Dataset';
  // Table
  var tableId = 'my table';
    
  // WRITE_APPEND: If the table already exists, BigQuery appends the data to the table.
  var writeDispositionSetting = 'WRITE_APPEND';
  
  // The name of the sheet in the Google Spreadsheet to export to BigQuery:
  var sheetName = 'src_cogs_playup_current';
  Logger.log(sheetName)
  
  var file = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('src_cogs_playup_current');
  Logger.log(file)
  // This represents ALL the data
  var rows = file.getDataRange().getValues();
  var rowsCSV = rows.join("\n");
  var blob = Utilities.newBlob(rowsCSV, "text/csv");
  var data = blob.setContentType('application/octet-stream');
  Logger.log(rowsCSV)
  
  // Create the data upload job. 
  var job = {
    configuration: {
      load: {
        destinationTable: {
          projectId: projectId,
          datasetId: datasetId,
          tableId: tableId
        },
        skipLeadingRows: 1,
        writeDisposition: writeDispositionSetting
      }
    }
  };
  Logger.log(job)

  
  // send the job to BigQuery so it will run your query  
  var runJob = BigQuery.Jobs.insert(job, projectId, data);
  //Logger.log('row 61  '+ runJob.status);
  var jobId = runJob.jobReference.jobId
  Logger.log('jobId: ' + jobId);
  Logger.log('row 61  '+ runJob.status);
  Logger.log('FINISHED!');
 // }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you could do that by making your self....the account that will execute the apps script, the owner access to the replicated google sheets....

and then all you have to do is iterate the code for each of the replicated google sheets full url

like this pseudo algorithm:

```
foreach(google sheets url)
{
   execute_the_insert(google sheets url);
}
```

Thanks for the code example...will try that....i think it is a clean code

@Scott Elliot